# Compare different collections and and take a value

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to find a nice / elegant (maybe using lodash) way to do compare 2 different colections and on equality (according to my defenition of equal) take some value from 1 collection and another value from the other collection and map it to a new collection, like so:

```
const filter1 = [{
    columnName : "date",
    value : "12/5"
},
{
    columnName : "age",
    value : "12"
}]
const filter2 = [{
    valueName : "age",
    displayName: "Age"
},
{
    valueName : "date",
    displayName: "DateD"
}]

filter1.map((val) => ({
  displayName: filter2.find(filter => filter.valueName === val.columnName).displayName,
  value : val.value
}))
```

to get:

```
[{
  displayName: "DateD",
  value: "12/5"
}, {
  displayName: "Age",
  value: "pa"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the 2nd array to a Map using `valueName` as the rest of the object as the value. Create the new array by mapping the 1st array, getting the items from the Map using `columnName` and merging it with the values from the 1st array using object spread.

```js
const fn = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const arr2Map = new Map(arr2.map(({ valueName, ...rest }) => [valueName, rest]))
  
  return arr1.map(({ columnName, ...rest }) => ({
    ...arr2Map.get(columnName),
    ...rest
  }))
}

const filter1 = [{"columnName":"date","value":"12/5"},{"columnName":"age","value":"12"}]
const filter2 = [{"valueName":"age","displayName":"Age"},{"valueName":"date","displayName":"DateD"}]

const result = fn(filter1, filter2)

console.log(result)
```